# To bind grid view with textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

In the below code i have a session value in which i have to pass to the grid and bind the values.The grid consists of textboxes if the session values is 2 there should be two row of textbox.I tried it throws index was out of range.Pls help me to over this issue.

```
int GoodsReceivedNoteID = (int)Session["GoodsReceivedNoteID"];
for (int iRow = 0; iRow < GoodsReceivedNoteID; iRow++)
{
    TextBox txtFreightCharges = (TextBox)gvGRN.Rows[iRow].Cells[6].FindControl("txtFreightCharges");
    TextBox txtLoadingCost = (TextBox)gvGRN.Rows[iRow].Cells[6].FindControl("txtLoadingCost");
    TextBox txtUnloadingCost = (TextBox)gvGRN.Rows[iRow].Cells[6].FindControl("txtUnloadingCost");
    TextBox txtInsuranseCost = (TextBox)gvGRN.Rows[iRow].Cells[6].FindControl("txtInsuranseCost");
    TextBox txtOtherExpenses = (TextBox)gvGRN.Rows[iRow].Cells[6].FindControl("txtOtherExpenses");
}
```

Comment: Does gvGRN.Rows have value(s)?

Comment: is everything supposed to go in to cell 6 ? then you just overwrite everything. Try replace Cells[6] in to Cells[n] where n = 0 to 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `Rows[index].Cells[6].FindControl`, the cell is not the `NamingContainer` of a control in a `GridViewRow`'s TemplateField but the row itself. I also  don't understand the relation between your session value and the number of rows in the grid. This is  simpler and more readable:

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in gvGRN.Rows)
{
    TextBox txtFreightCharges = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtFreightCharges");
    TextBox txtLoadingCost = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtLoadingCost");
    TextBox txtUnloadingCost = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtUnloadingCost");
    TextBox txtInsuranseCost = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtInsuranseCost");
    TextBox txtOtherExpenses = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtOtherExpenses");
}
```

If you only want to take `GoodsReceivedNoteID`-rows (which sounds wrong since an ID is not a counter):

```
for(int i = 0; i < GoodsReceivedNoteID; i++))
{
    GridViewRow row = gvGRN.Rows[i];
    TextBox txtFreightCharges = (TextBox)row.FindControl("txtFreightCharges");
    // ...
}
```